# Year picker user control in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, datepicker, sharepoint-2013

I want to know is there any SharePoint native user control for year picker? I know there was another library like jQuery and other thing that do like what I want. I need SharePoint control for some localization issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no yearpicker control but you can use the SharePoint DateTimeControl for selecting dates or datetimes. 
Unfortunately i think its rather hard to customize it to only select years. Therefor i would suggest to use an external lib for that or just use a dropdown with dates to select?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimecontrol.aspx